# Passing a reference to an object into anonymous function

Tags: jquery

I need to pass a reference to the current object into an anonymous function. In Mootools it would be something like this:

```
    this.start = function(){

        this.intervalId = setInterval(function(){

            this.elapsedTime ++;
            this.setTime();

        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
```

But I need it to be done using jQuery and such syntax is not supported in jQuery. What can I do? I tried:

```
    this.start = function(){

        var thisObj = this;
        this.intervalId = setInterval(function(){

            thisObj.elapsedTime ++;
            thisObj.setTime();

        }, 1000);
    }
```

But it looks like thisObj is simply a new object because some of its methods which were assigned values in the init method are now empty.

Please advise :)

Comment: No, this should work. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. It could depend on how you call `start`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work, `thisObj` does **not** reference a new object. It references `this`. If this code does not work, it means that you are not calling `start()` correctly and even `bind()` would not help you here.

So you have to fix your code first, make sure you are calling `start()` the right way, like `myobj.start()`.

But in any case, jQuery provides the [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method:

```
this.intervalId = setInterval($.proxy(function(){
    this.elapsedTime ++;
    this.setTime();
}, this), 1000);
```

which does the same as `.bind()`.

Comment: Thank you. I now have this:

            console.log(this.timerInputs.hours);
            this.intervalId = setInterval($.proxy(function(){
            console.log(this.timerInputs.hours);
                
                this.elapsedTime ++;
                this.setTime();
                
            }, this), 1000);

This is a script for a timer so the this.timerInputs.hours is an input object for hours. The thing is that  console.log(this.timerInputs.hours); before setInterval return a valid object but right after setInterval it returns an empty object

Answer (score 1):

<strike>change `thisObj` to a global so it exists outside of your `start` function. The way you had it the `setInterval` function call wouldn't know what `thisObj` was</strike>

```
var thisObj = null;

this.start = function(){

    thisObj = this;
    this.intervalId = setInterval(function(){

        thisObj.elapsedTime ++;
        thisObj.setTime();

    }, 1000);
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/Swh9U/

---

And to prove Felix's point, OP's code does work: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/Swh9U/1/

Comment: The OP's code should work. Lifting the variable in a higher scope should not make a difference. The function passed to `setInterval` is a closure which has access to the variables defined inside `start`.